# Device browser URL detection in Xamarin forms

Tags: url, xamarin.forms, google-signin, mobile-browser

I am trying to integrate Google plus login into my Xamarin application. Since, Google has removed support for the Authentication of the webviews. I have tried to launch the google api which will redirect to the Sign in page for google in the mobile browser using the below code.

```
Device.OpenUri(new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth"))
```

Using the above code, i am able to launch the Google api Login page, but need to detect and read the URL in the mobile browser from the Xamarin application after the user login to their account in the Google Login page.

Please suggest me how to read the URL when the user signed in so that i can get the access_token from google to get the user's information to show in my application.

**Note:** I am developing cross platform xamarin app not developing separately for Android and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you will need some platform-specific code to do this, both for Android and iOS.

The key though is to make the callback URL invoke your app via a URL scheme.

I have a Xamarin Forms iOS example here: http://damianblog.com/2017/03/20/google-signin-ios-xamarin-forms/

Comment: Thanks Damian. I am currently working on android, i will look into your sample while going for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

use [Xamarin.Auth](https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.auth) for authentication

Comment: I am currently using Xamarin.Auth. thanks for the reply Pratik